# Is is possible to eliminate space between non-stroked polygons in Processing? If so, how?

Tags: image-processing, processing

I'm working on a Processing project to simulate very basic hard-shadows.  For the most part I've got it working; each edge of each object checks if its back is facing the light.  If it is, a shadow polygon is added using that edge and others cast back away from the point directly away from the light.

However, when I tried to shift from solid shadows to transparent I ran into some problems.  Namely, because the shadows are made of multiple shapes the borders tended to overlap, making them darker than everywhere else:

[image: Shadows with Lines Between Them]

I disabled the stroke on the shadows, which improved the effect but left small lines between the shadows, despite the edges for the polygons being identical:

[image: Shadows with Space Between Them]

Is there a way to eliminate this artifact?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to not draw the shadows as separate pieces, but to draw the combined polygon of all the shadow pieces as one polygon.

Here's a little example that exhibits your problem:

```
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){

  background(255);

  noStroke();

  fill(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);

  fill(128, 128, 128, 128);

  beginShape();
  vertex(mouseX, mouseY);
  vertex(0, height);
  vertex(width, height);
  endShape();

  fill(128, 128, 128, 128);

  beginShape();
  vertex(mouseX, mouseY);
  vertex(width, height);
  vertex(width, 0);
  endShape();
}
```

Notice the white line between the two polygons:

[image: shadows with line between them]

But if I instead draw the two polygons as one:

```
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){

  background(255);

  noStroke();

  fill(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);

  fill(128, 128, 128, 128);

  beginShape();
  vertex(mouseX, mouseY);
  vertex(0, height);
  vertex(width, height);
  vertex(width, 0);
  endShape();
}
```

Then the white line goes away:

[image: shadows with no line between them]

Comment: This would work, but would be slower, as it would require a additional steps to find which shadows can be combined, and then combining them...  I'll look into it, and unless a better answer arises I'll give this one correct.

Comment: @TimothyS. I'm not sure your assumption that it would be slower is correct. After all, creating and drawing a single polygon might be faster than drawing multiple polygons!

Comment: True enough, the rendering may be faster.  I was thinking about the time necessary to determine which of the polygons are adjacent/can be combined.  What I've done instead is alter my algorithm to look for an edge that won't be casting a shadow (assuming the shape is closed there must be one, I think), then start with that edge, and combine as I go around.  Works right, and it's faster.  Thanks.